# How to remove extra commas in my string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

Here is my code for storing in a string and reading from a list:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

String listString = "";

for (String s : list)
{
    listString += s + ", ";
}

System.out.println(listString);
```

It is adding extra comma at the end, how can i remove the and do the code in minimum number of lines. Please help!

Comment: It won't add any commas in the end.

Comment: Use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 8 has a nice new [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class which was made just for this...

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

String listString = "";
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (String s : list) {
    sj.add(s);
}
listString = sj.toString();
System.out.println(listString);
```

Which outputs

```
one, two, three
```

If you're not lucky enough to be using Java 8 (and I feel your pain), then you could use `StringBuilder` and simply delete the last two characters from the end, something like...

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

String listString = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
for (String s : list) {
    sb.append(s).append(", ");
}
listString = sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length()).toString();
System.out.println(listString);
```

Now, obviously, you should check to see if the length of resulting `StringBuilder` is long enough (has content) before doing the delete, but I'll leave that up to you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

System.out.println(list.toString().replaceAll("\\]|\\[", ""));
```

Output:

```
one, two, three
```

Comment: `System.out.println(list);` also gives same output.

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative to the `StringJoiner` and other classes you could also just initialize `listString` with the first element, add the comma before the next element and start the iteration at index 1. You just can´t use the foreach anymore.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
String listString = list.get(0);

for (int i = 1;i<list.size();++i) {
    listString += ", " + list.get(i);
}

System.out.println(listString);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
listString = listString.substring(0, listString.length() - 2);
System.out.println(listString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

String listString = "";

for (String s : list)
{
  listString += ", " + s;
}

System.out.println(listString.replaceFirst(",",""));
```

You can use above code. Append comma at start and then replacefirst comma with blank string.

Comment: i think you should replace ", " with "" else there will be extra space at beginning

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution.

```
if (list.endsWith(",")) {
  list= list.substring(0, list.length() - 1);
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Prior Java 8:**

```
StringBuilder listString = new StringBuilder();
 for (String id : list){
       listString.append(id).append(",");
 }
String result =listString.toString().replaceAll(",$", "");
```

Regex `",$"` is to detect the last comma.

**With Java 8:**

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```